# Как скомпилировать SDL 2.0 под MinGW

Tags: c++, sdl

Целый день мучаюсь вроде все правильно делаю, все пути к библиотекам .lib и .h правильны несколько раз проверял, использую Win7x32 и версии SDL тоже x32 скачал, но не компилируется. Компилирую вот так: `g++ test_sdl.cpp -o  test_sdl.exe -I"C:\mycpp\SDL\include" -L"C:\mycpp\SDL\lib" -lmingw32` Если добавить `-lSDL2main -lSDL2` выдает ошибку Вот код: [ссылка на исходник](https://pastebin.com/fNJ8JKLs)
А вот что выдает компилятор: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Установил последнюю версию SDL2 (2.0.7-dev) и заменил обратные слеши на прямые в путях. И все собралось. Со старой версией SDL2 (2.0.4) ничего не помогало (да там даже имена библиотек неправильные для GCC). Система: Win 7x64 Pro, собирал с MingW-w64 GCC 7.1.0 (думаю, 7-я версия GCC тут не так важна) как 32-битное приложение.

gcc version 7.1.0 (i686-posix-sjlj-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

вот команда:
g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -I"d:/lib/SDL2-2.0.7/i686-w64-mingw32/include" -L"d:/lib/SDL2-2.0.7/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/" -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

Отсюда видно и новую версию и где она у меня живет.
И еще, автор вдохновения здесь (откуда взялись такие параметры для сборки): http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/mingw/index.php

PS: на -lSDL2 для старой версии библиотеки SDL2 g++ выдает ошибку, т.к. GCC ожидает имя типа libSDL2.a, а есть только SDL2.a или даже SDL2.lib... но даже если библиотеку подложить как просто объектный файл, то все-равно идут ошибки при сборке. Как я понял, это была проблема самой SDL2 ранних версий в сочетании с MingW.